# What is the meaning of this sentence. "feared murdered'?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, headlinese

I saw this sentence on the internet. But past verb after past verb, (feared murdered)? I wanna know the meaning of this sentence. How can I translate this sentence?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is typical headline writer's way of condensing information into as few words as possible. Translated it means

> It is suspected that Vito Corleone has been murdered

In this context **feared = suspected** with an element of dread or sadness. So "We  fear ..." can be read as "Unfortunately we suspect / believe ..."

Comment: In other words: it is not an English sentence. It is [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese)

Comment: thank you so much for your kind information.

Answer (score 3):

It's "headlinese", which is a slangy term for the kind of "reduced, cut down" syntax used in newspaper headlines to save space and grab the reader's attention. The "full" sentence would be...

> ***Vito Corleone is feared murdered***
> ...more naturally, if it wasn't a *headline* (and if we still wanted the passive format)...
> ***It is feared that Vito Corleone has been murdered***

... where *to fear that X [is true]* means *to **believe** that X (something bad) is true*. I assume that *in context* it's a joke. There's stuff going on in the real world right now with drug baron Dairo Antonio Úsuga (Otoniel) and others, but Vito Corleone is the fictitious mob leader in *The Godfather (1972).*

We get quite a few questions on ELL asking about the syntax of headlines, which are often "invalid" in terms of traditional grammar. My advice to learners is you shouldn't bother trying to understand how "headlinese" syntax works. Only look into it if you find the same construction in *other* texts (including a *newspaper article* itself; just ignore the *headline*).

Comment: thank you so much. It helps a lot.